CrBasic can not using UDPDataGram to send data to NodeJS server
I have nodejs UDP server like this:
const dgram = require('node:dgram');
const server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

server.on('connect', () => {
    console.log(`connect`);
    server.close();
});

server.on('close', () => {
    console.log(`close`);
});

server.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log(`error ${error}`);
});

server.on('listening', () => {
    const address = server.address();
    console.log(`server listening ${address.address}:${address.port} - :${address.family}`);
});
  

server.on('message', (msg, rinfo) => {
  console.log(`Received message: ${msg} from ${rinfo.address}:${rinfo.port}`);
});

server.bind(6787);

I am writing code to send data from datalogger CR1000X to this server, here is what is test:
UDPDataGram("192.168.31.112",6787,"test",100,0,0)

192.168.31.112 is my server ip
But when running program, I did not see any log from server. That mean the datalogger can not send, or send wrong,.. can someone help?
I tried to write a UDP node client from other device, then it worked, but the datalogger seem can not to be sent
const dgram = require('dgram');
const client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

const message = Buffer.from('Hello World!');

client.send(message, 6787, "192.168.31.112", (err) => {
    console.log(err)
  client.close();
});

client.on('message', (msg, rinfo) => {
  console.log(`Received response from ${rinfo.address}:${rinfo.port}: ${msg}`);
});

